# Searching for special services using the protocol Bonjour in python

Tags: python, bonjour

How can I specify the browse for services which are published under this format:
"_namemaster-master._tcp".
I am using Python.

Comment: Have you checked [pybonjour](http://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/) yet and looked at their examples?

Comment: Yes I did it. But I am working with bonjour-py.My problem is how to specify the type of the service that I am browsing about.

Comment: Yes I did it. But I am working with bonjour-py.My problem is how to specify the type of the service that I am browsing about since I have many services to be discovered and each one of them has his own "namemaster" but they share the same ending which is "-master._tcp". By the way there is no  unique type of service to search for.

Comment: It's been a while since I have used bonjour (with pybonjour). If the number of different service types is manageable, you could maybe just launch a separate query for all different services and combine the results in the callback function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I'll browse for all existing bonjour services which are published in my local network, what should be exactly the service type in python that I will browse for. For example something like '*'._tcp where '*' means all type services. Is such syntax valid? I didn't find any documentation about this in the Internet